# Excel VBA Combine duplicates and add column values

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Hi I want to create a code to arrange the data using vba but I don't know how.

I have a data that looks like this

```
     Col 1    |  Col 2   
1. Question 1 | Person 1 
1. Question 1 | Person 2 
1. Question 1 | Person 3 
2. Question 2 | Person 1 
2. Question 2 | Person 2 
2. Question 2 | Person 3 
3. Question 3 | Person 1 
3. Question 3 | Person 2 
3. Question 3 | Person 3
```

I want the output to look like this

```
Col 2    | Col 1
Person 1 | 1. Question 1
         | 2. Question 2
         | 3. Question 3
-------------------------
Person 2 | 1. Question 1
         | 2. Question 2
         | 3. Question 3
-------------------------
Person 3 | 1. Question 1
         | 2. Question 2
         | 3. Question 3
```

I don't know how to make this using vba. please help me on this.

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  You may not need VBA.  Have you looked at pivot tables?

Comment: Hi @ReyJuna, yes I've tried pivot tables but I have a desired format for the output. and I'm stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly, without optimization and any checks:

```vb
Sub ReSort(src As Range, dst As Range)
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, tmp, temp()
' Copy source range
temp = src.Value
' Sort data
For i = LBound(temp, 1) To UBound(temp, 1) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(temp, 1)
        If (temp(i, 2) > temp(j, 2)) Or ((temp(i, 2) = temp(j, 2)) And (temp(i, 1) > temp(j, 1))) Then
            tmp = temp(i, 1)
            temp(i, 1) = temp(j, 1)
            temp(j, 1) = tmp
            tmp = temp(i, 2)
            temp(i, 2) = temp(j, 2)
            temp(j, 2) = tmp
        End If
    Next j
Next i
' Clear vertical dups
For i = UBound(temp, 1) - 1 To LBound(temp, 1) Step -1
    If temp(i + 1, 2) = temp(i, 2) Then
        temp(i + 1, 2) = ""
    End If
Next i
' Swap columns
For i = LBound(temp, 1) To UBound(temp, 1)
    tmp = temp(i, 1)
    temp(i, 1) = temp(i, 2)
    temp(i, 2) = tmp
Next i
' Store result
dst.Value = temp
End Sub
```

`src` may be equal to `dst` if you want to overwrite. For example,

```vb
Call ReSort(Range("A1:B9"), Range("A1:B9"))
```

Comment: Hi I've tried your code but it gives me an error on copy of source. "Runtime error "9"" Subscript out of range

Comment: @gee Trace the code. Detect the operator which causes the error, and look all variables values in Locals window.

Comment: ohh I figured it but I have another error on LBOUND and UBOUND function. it say that "Run-time error '6': Overflow". I not familiar with those functions.

Comment: @gee *I have another error on LBOUND and UBOUND function* o_O Check in Locals - `temp` variable datatype must be 2-dimentional Array of Variants after `temp = src.Value` code line execution... Check if these functions are available itself (execute example code from help). And check that you copypast my code into new common module, and no global variables which interfere with variable names used in my code.

Comment: @gee *what I have more than 282 rows?* I have tested my code on 1000 rows array - 0.582 sec, and on 10000 rows array - 32.5 sec. Replacing the bubble sorting code with more effective one (for example, quicksort) may increase performance. *I declare Call ReSort(Range("A:B"), Range("A:B"))* In that case you tries to scan the whole (1M) rows... If you want to use column-ranged addresses, create wrapping procedure which detects the last used cell in a source range, build its address as rectangle-ranged, build proper destination range, then call my code.

Comment: @gee If source range do not contain holes, you can use something like `src.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address` for to find data bounds. Or `src.End(xlDown).Address`.